# React native view fails to refresh after the state variable updated

Tags: react-native, web-services

I am new to React and have difficulties on refresh data in the .  I am expecting that the view should shows

"Hello World! Shyam"

But it only shows "Hellow World".

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class WhatsDes extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {name:'', email:''};
            }
  
  
  render() {
      console.log('Start render ....');
      const url = 'http://192.168.1.13:8091/employees';  
      fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJson => {
          console.log('ok 1: '+ JSON.stringify(responseJson));
          console.log('ok 2: '+responseJson[0].name);
          this.state.name = responseJson[0].name;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log('error' +error);
        });  
    console.log('Show view ...' );
    console.log('this.state.name ...' + this.state.name);
    return (
      
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Text>Hello, world ! {this.state.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Log output:

```
LOG  Running "WhatsDes" with {"rootTag":201}
 LOG  Start render ....
 LOG  Show view ...
 LOG  this.state.name ...
 LOG  ok 1: [{"name":"Shyam","email":"shyamjaiswal@gmail.com"},{"name":"Bob","email":"bob32@gmail.com"},{"name":"Jai","email":"jai87@gmail.com"}]
 LOG  ok 2: Shyam
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not mutate state. If you want to update state, use the `setState` method.

change your state update,

```js
this.state.name = responseJson[0].name;
```

to

```js
this.setState({name: responseJson[0].name});
```

Read more about `setState` at https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Edit: Upon close inspection, noticed a few more no no in your code.

You are doing all these actions inside of the `render` function. This is not the correct way of doing it.

Move your API calls to `componentDidMount` function, which will only be executed on your component mount. Doing it in `render` as you are doing now will repeatedly call that function on each render and will throw error `Max callstack exceeded`.

Change your code to,

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class WhatsDes extends Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {name:'', email:''};
  }
   
  componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'http://192.168.1.13:8091/employees';  
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState({ name: responseJson[0].name });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('error' +error);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Text>Hello, world ! {this.state.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

perhaps a good idea to look through the [Life cycle events - React](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Comment: Great! It works now but here come another question.  It seems that it goes into infinite loop.  (It keeps calling the web-service)

Comment: That was because you had that call in your `render` function. move it to `componentDidMount`